# Python Pandas subtracting each column and creating new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the following columns:

January, February, March, April

I want to subtract February with January. March with February. April with March etc. Then for each of these calculations a new column to be created with the calculation.

I have tried creating a for loop, but not it did not work as I am not certain how to store each calculation into a new column and how to state February - previous column etc.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Dataframe example:

```
Sales January February March April 
Team1 1000    2000     3000  4000
Team2 1000    2000     3000  4000
```

Dataframe result:

```
Sales January diff February diff March  diff   April 
Team1 1000    1000 2000     1000 3000    1000  4000
Team2 1000    1000 2000     1000 3000    1000  4000
```

Comment: What kind of data are these columns holding? Please put a sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = pd.concat([
    df,
    df.loc[:, 'January':] \
        .diff(axis=1) \
        .drop(columns='January') \
        .add_suffix('_diff')    
], axis=1)
```

Try this:

```
df = pd.concat([
    df,
    df.loc[:, 'January':] \
        .diff(axis=1) \
        .drop(columns='January') \
        .add_suffix('_diff')
], axis=1)
```

What it does:

- `df.loc[:, 'January':]` takes all columns from `January` and to the right
- `.diff(axis=1)` calculate the difference with the previous column
- `.drop(columns='January')` drops the difference column for Jan since it's all n/a
- `.add_suffix('_diff')` renames `February` to `February_diff` and so on

The outer `concat` is to add the diff columns back to your original dataframe

Comment: that is amazing thank you. Is the reason I do not need to loop through each column to subtract with the previous column, due to using the diff method?